# By using proportional editing, vertices are moved in the wrong axis

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, axis

So I am following Andrew Price's 2.8 Donut tutorial but sometimes (not always) when I move vertices with Proportional editing, it moves the vertices around it really unpredictably (see screenshots below).

I don't know how to make it all move adjacent to the camera rather than bits shooting off that I didn't even grab directly in the first place.

Is there any way I can do this?

---Screenshots---

Before:

[image]

Grabbing with PE (looks fine):

[image]

After:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you applied scale to the object? Object>Apply>Scale. Did you use "Connected" in proportional editing? Also have you checked that X-mirror is not enabled in options?