# "Connected" option tickbox after Move

Tags: vertices

I am following Andrew Price's donut tutorial material for Blender 2.8 (though I'm running 2.82.a-3) and I am struggling to understand one issue.

When attempting to Move a section of a mesh with Proportional Editing on and a Smooth Falloff, some of the vertices get shot around in crazy directions. Much like [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/151021/by-using-proportional-editing-vertices-are-moved-in-the-wrong-axis) poster experienced.

As the several-questions-as-an-answer accepted answer post gets to, I have adopted "Connected" as my solution. However, until the writing of this post, my "workflow" was to move the selected vertex where I wanted it to be, then check "Connected" in the follow-on options dialog. I noticed that if I do this, it fixes the mesh. More confusingly, though, if I then proceed to uncheck the box, the mesh remains as I would've liked it to be and, in this case, the icing actually flattens a little better against the donut. Axis mirroring was not on, so I just used this check->uncheck method to fix all of my moved vertices.

Anywho... the actual question: What are the use cases and caveats for both connected proportional falloff and disconnected proportional falloff? Should I just always have connected on? Why, specifically, do disconnected proportional moves cause all that vertex skewing?

Thank you in advance. =)